# this.setState() is not a function when using react with jquery inside componentDidmount

Tags: jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6, this

When I use react with es6 and jquery's ajax function, I got `this.setState() is not a function` error. I tried bind this within constructor using `this.componentDidmount = this.componentDidmount.bind(this);`, but still not working.

Can any one help me? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

class UserGist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userName: '',
      lastGistUrl: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
      let lastGist = result[0];
      this.setState({
        userName: lastGist.owner.login,
        lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
      });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.userName}'s last gist is
        <a href={this.state.lastGistUrl}>here</a>.
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default UserGist;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` context for the callback function inside `componentDidMount()` isn't set.

You could use an arrow function to do it, like so:

```
this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, (result) => {
  let lastGist = result[0];
  this.setState({
    userName: lastGist.owner.login,
    lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
  });
})
```

Comment: when I remove `this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.componentWillUnmount = this.componentWillUnmount.bind(this);`, it also works, does this two functions auto bind `this` ?

Comment: Yes, all React lifecycle methods are autobound for you. The issue you were having was that you tried to use 'this' in an asynchronous code - a callback function. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/3979621 for explanation.

Comment: @freddy: *"Yes, all React lifecycle methods are autobound for you."* No. `React.createClass` did that, but that doesn't happen with the `class` syntax.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, yes, you are right. However, could you please give an example where `this` in a lifecycle method would not refer to an instance of the class containing the method when used synchronously?

Comment: @freddy: There is none. Inside a lifecycle method, `this` will always refer to the React component.